# Merge sorting a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to use merge sort, to sort all the characters in a string. But I am always having some compilation problems. Specifically I am having problems at lines: [if (s[i1].compare(s[i2]) < 0)] and [s[from + j] = b[j];].
Any help please?

```
void mergeSort(string &s, int from, int to)
{
    if (from == to)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = (from + to) / 2;
    mergeSort(s, from, mid);
    mergeSort(s, mid + 1, to);
    merge(s, from, mid, to);

}

 void merge(string &s, int from, int mid, int to)
 {
    int n = to - from + 1;
    vector<string> b(n); // merge both halves into a temporary vector b
    int i1 = from;  
    int i2 = mid + 1; 
    int j = 0;


    while (i1 <= mid && i2 <= to)
    {
        if (s[i1].compare(s[i2]) < 0)
        {
            b[j] = s[i1];
            i1++;
        }
        else
        {
            b[j] = s[i2];
            i2++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    // copy any remaining entries of the first half
    while (i1 <= mid)
    {
        b[j] = s[i1];
        i1++;
        j++;
    }

    // copy any remaining entries of the second half
    while (i2 <= to)
    {
        b[j] = s[i2];
        i2++;
        j++;
    }
    // copy back from the temporary array
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        s[from + j] = b[j];
    }
 } 

int main(){
string str = "cdebfag"
if (str.length() >= 2 )
mergeSort(str, 0, str.length() - 1);

//print sorted
cout << str << endl;

return 0;
```

}

The errors are:

> request for member 'compare' in '(& s)->std::__cxx11::basic_string::operator', which is of non-class type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'}

and

> invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string&'} from expression of type 'std::vector >'

Answer (score 2):

`s[i]` is not a `string` it's a `char` and `char` does not have any member functions.

Rather than :

```
if (s[i1].compare(s[i2]) < 0)
```

You should try something like :

```
if (s[i1] < s[i2])
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sid's answer, you should make `vector<char> b` instead of `vector<string> b`.